# Azure Back Ground Services For File Processing

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-aks, azure-appfabric

We currently have Window service to process Inbound/outbound files.
In Bound files we read data and perform some calculations and store data in Database.
Out Bound files we generate data from the database.

We want to migrate to azure now. I have following questions .

1) what is the best way to store files in azure (Blob or File Share in azure) . We have only ".pdf,.txt,.xlsx" formats no videos

2) Which process is better to process files - WebJobs, Virtual Machine and install window service , Azure Batch Jobs, azure kubernetes service,Service Fabric.

Please some can help me on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

How are you receiving the files API, FTP or some other way?  There are a ton of details that are needed to really answer this, but here are my thoughts.
Blob storage would be more cost effective.  You only need to use a file share if you want to be able to map a network drive from a VM. 
  If processing one file would complete in less than 10 minutes I would look at Azure functions for that.  If you’re processing thousands of files per day Azure functions would be expensive so I would look at running them on an App Service on VMs or moving to Service Fabric.
  If you have a web site that’s used to upload the files and  you’re already using Azure App service then you could use Web Jobs.

Comment: Thanks for Response. We are using FTP to receive file from third party and windows service will process those files. We process almost 500 files per day and each file process take mores than 10-15 minutes .


Mostly, we are looking for PAAS not to go with IAAS.Is that ok to run this process as web jobs or it will more cost effective .

Instead of Blob , can i use file share and directly save files(outbound files) to File share using web jobs ?

Comment: Are you willing to make substantial code changes to the Windows Service?  Do you have an existing web app you're hosting on an App Service Plan?   How resource intensive is processing these files in terms of CPU and RAM?

Comment: Yes , We are ready to change code of window service to make it azure compatibility. Yes we have .Net Web API hosted. We can create separate website for this process and create web job  in this webapp. Not much resource intensive only time consuming process.